# Exporting DER public key in .NET 5

Tags: c#, openssl, bouncycastle, .net-5

I am working on a C#/.NET 5 class to calculate a Docker "libtrust" key Id for an RSA keypair. Given a PEM-encoded private key, I can do this easily at the commandline using `openssl`:

```
$ cat some.key | openssl rsa -pubout -outform der | openssl sha256 -binary | base32 | sed 's/.\{4\}/&:/g' | cut -c1-59
writing RSA key
RKVW:DS7B:7HXK:AAUH:QJ4U:Z5ZP:TKPL:NMZ2:LYSM:XKN5:PE2L:L23Y
```

And I can achieve the same thing in .NET using BouncyCastle:

```cs
var reader = new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(new StringReader(pem));
var keyPair = (Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)reader.ReadObject();
var publicKey = Org.BouncyCastle.X509.SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(keyPair.Public).GetDerEncoded();
var kidHash = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(publicKey);
var kidBase32 = SimpleBase.Base32.Rfc4648.Encode(kidHash);
var chunks = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    chunks.Add(kidBase32[(i * 4)..(i * 4 + 4)]);
}
var kid = string.Join(':', chunks);
```

However, I'd like to avoid using a 3rd party library if at all possible. I can trivially load the PEM key, and export the public component in PKCS#1:

```cs
var rsa = System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportFromPem(pem);            
var der = rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey(); // Exports the public-key portion of the current key in the PKCS#1 RSAPublicKey format.
```

My understanding is that PKCS#1 and DER should be equivalent here; both are exporting the public key in ASN.1 format + DER encoding. And when I compare the raw output values from `openssl`, BouncyCastle, and .NET, they're *almost* identical. Almost, but not quite; the `openssl` and BouncyCastle versions have some kind of "header" block of about 24 bytes, which the .NET version is missing. For my test key, the header looks like this:

```
30 82 02 22 30 0D 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01 01 05 00 03 82 02 0F 00
```

The remaining 526 bytes are identical across all three versions.

What is this extra data at the beginning of the openssl/BouncyCastle DER, and how can I either get .NET to output it, or produce it myself?

Comment: Try `var der = rsa.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()` instead.

Comment: Yup, that works!